# Programmatically "liking" a page on Facebook via API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

Although it's documented that this is supposedly possible, the API currently doesn't allow "liking" of a page within Facebook via the OpenGraph API (i.e. "OBJECT_ID/likes"). The error "Application does not have the capability to make this API call." appears no matter what permissions have been granted.

Is there any plan to fix this? Does anyone know of a work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible for an app to natively facebook-like Facebook Page or a URL via the API. This is only possible through the Like button.

However, with the advent of the new Open Graph (custom objects and actions) you can create your own custom Like action, and allow users to 'like' objects on your app's domain via the API. These are not native Facebook likes, but they appear a "User liked X" in the newsfeed.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible and if the documentation suggests that it is please file a bug report with the details. This hasn't ever been possible as far as I know and I don't think it will be made possible in the short term at least. 
Only photos, posts, etc, can be liked